# Shorten a VB.NET array declaration?

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays

Question: How to shorten this array creation ?
I need to create an array of type ReportingService2005_WebService.Property with one property.

Something like:

```
Dim PropertyArray() as new  ReportingService2005_WebService.Property(1)
```

I have to do this:

```
        Dim PropertyArray As ReportingService2005_WebService.Property() = New ReportingService2005_WebService.Property(0) {}
        PropertyArray(0) = New ReportingService2005_WebService.Property
        PropertyArray(0).Name = "Description"
        PropertyArray(0).Value = "Automatically added DataSource"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/02/05/vb-net-9-0-object-and-array-initializers.aspx

```
Dim PropertyArray() As ReportingService2005_WebService.Property = { _
    new ReportingService2005_WebService.Property() With {.Name = "Description", .Value="Automatically added DataSource" } _
}
```

Make sure your "array brackets" are in the correct place in the initial Dim statement.  Should be:
Dim PropertyArray()...

Comment: what version of VB.NET is required? E.g. would it work with the version of VB.NET corresponding to Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: as per that link in my post it is VB.NET v9, which is VS2008.